# Async method with three internal tasks

Tags: c#, async-await

Consider we have three different database stores which we want to find an Id which is unique in all this three. I mean if we query first data store and we find that id. It's over and there is no need to further attempt, if that Id is in non of this three data stores we return null, I'm new in asynchronous programming, I wanted to know if there is any better implementation for this lines of code? I mean less if/else?

```
 public async Task<WebData> GetDataByIdAsync(GetDataById input)
    {
        var twitterData = await DataAccess.FindDataById<TwitterData>(input.Id);
        WebData result;
        if (twitterData  == null)
        {
            var facebookData = await DataAccess.FindDataById<FacebookData>(input.Id);
            if facebookData == null)
            {
                var linkedinData = await DataAccess.FindDataById<LinkedinData>(input.Id);
                if linkedinData == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                result = linkedinData 
            }
            else
            {
                result = facebookData;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result = twitterData ;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the return pattern:

```
public async Task<WebData> GetDataByIdAsync(GetDataById input) 
{ 
    var twitterData = await DataAccess.FindDataById<TwitterData>(input.Id); 
    if (twitterData != null)
    {
        return twitterData;
    } 

    var facebookData = await DataAccess.FindDataById<FacebookData>(input.Id); 
    if (facebookData != null) 
    {
        return facebookData;
    } 

    var linkedinData = await DataAccess.FindDataById<LinkedinData>(input.Id); 
    if (linkedinData != null) 
    { 
        return linkedinData; 
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Are early returns a "pattern" now?

Comment: What is actually needed to be called a pattern?

Comment: @ABravoDev: Multiple steps/parts that commonly appear together to solve a common problem, but are not baked into the language.

Comment: This is crying out for a method to call some DAO with an id. You can the same code 3 times.

Comment: @Bergi Probably a code style pattern, not software design pattern.

Comment: @cHao Interesting... then my "pattern" matches that definition (it's a common problem, you need to take it step by step; and conditional statements and return is not specific to this language, though they are language that don't have them)

Comment: @BoristheSpider You are absolutely right! But I dont know what FindDataById does... perhaps we are running in circles.

Comment: @ABravoDev: Not "specific to the language". "Baked into the language". Patterns, i'd argue, require something extra that the language doesn't provide. (The only reason patterns exist is to solve problems the language hasn't already solved for you.) Early return (and guard clauses, which are a very closely related concept) might more properly be called an idiom.

Answer (score 52):

Short and clean using [null-coalescing operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator):

```
public async Task<WebData> GetDataByIdAsync(GetDataById input) 
{ 
    return await DataAccess.FindDataById<TwitterData>(input.Id)?? 
           await DataAccess.FindDataById<FacebookData>(input.Id)??
           await DataAccess.FindDataById<LinkedinData>(input.Id); 
}
```

Comment: In this case, the Tasks are still executed one-at-a-time, correct?

Comment: @Aaron M. Eshbach , Absolutely because [the null coalescing operator is short circuit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318912/does-c-sharp-operator-short-circuit).

Answer (score 2):

An efficient way of doing this (if you don't care about the overhead on the data stores) would be to start all three tasks, then return when the first of the tasks produces a non-null value.  Something like this:

```
public async Task<WebData> GetDataByIdAsync(GetDataById input) 
{
    var remainingTasks = new HashSet<Task<WebData>>(new [] { DataAccess.FindDataById<TwitterData>(input.Id), DataAccess.FindDataById<FacebookData>(input.Id), DataAccess.FindDataById<LinkedinData>(input.Id) });

    while (remainingTasks.Any())
    {
        var firstCompleted = await Task.WhenAny(remainingTasks);
        if (firstCompleted.Result != null)
        {
             return firstCompleted.Result;
        }
        remainingTasks.Remove(firstCompleted);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: One downside to this approach is that you launch all three tasks and if one returns, any exceptions thrown by the later tasks go unobserved.

Comment: This wouldn't work if you cared about order, would it? e.g. if Facebook is fastest but you would prefer to use Twitter if available? Also, it's effectively non-deterministic and could produce different results if you run it multiple times.